# Where can I ask about a mathematical formula and the code written that runs it

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question about mathematics and javascript?

I have a mathematical formula and the code written that runs it in a *loop*, I also have the example in a jsfiddle.

My question would be; how do I reverse the effect of this formula.

The formula takes an input and gives me an output. I would like to take the output and have it return the input.

I am unsure though where on Stack Exchange is an appropriate place to ask Mathematics Stack Exchange would seem correct to me only for most of my examples are in javascript, so it might get closed as a programming question.